# Transfer of Big Data to remote server for saving

Tags: architecture, sql-server-2008-r2, bigdata, database, nosql

We have multiple Java applications that send their audit logs to a server using JMS to be saved into a SQL server database. One of these applications is generating messages at a higher rate than it is transferring them and so its queue gets backed up and runs out of space. Hundreds of millions of messages are being generated by this module and we need a fast transfer and save mechanism for these.

Possible solution we have thought of:
Have one central mongodb in place of the sql server and have local mongodbs in all modules. Audits get saved in the local dbs and a nightly job will dump and restore them into the central db.

Please explain the reasoning for your choice of solution.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment to SO users

Comment: Yes, it's a work assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with Apache Kafka instead of JMS.